# select query based on gridview data

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, gridview

the data is binded from popup gridview with list of employee data to be entered in grid 
once the select value its gets inserted in gridview .....what i need is the data displayed in gridview must not show in popup window grid ....the popup gridview is based on select query with data not in once inserted in my sqltable

```
           <Columns>              

               <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Intime">
              <ItemTemplate>
                  <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" eval(employee name)runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
              </ItemTemplate>
              <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
          </asp:TemplateField>
          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Outtime">
              <ItemTemplate>
                  <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
              </ItemTemplate>
              <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
          </asp:TemplateField>

           </Columns>


       </asp:GridView>
```

what i need is that send the datatable of grid to stored procedure in the select query is that possible ...any other solution to provide

Comment: Not sure I am understanding the question completely, but what I have done in past is create a xml string for my multiple rows of data and then parse that in my storedproc to store to DB.

Comment: Could you please explain your problem little more. Because it's hard to understand what you expected.